# MathGL libmgl.so.7.2.0 not found

Tags: c++, g++, mathgl

I have downloaded and compiled MathGL following the instructions on [sourceforge](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/Installation.html#Installation) without any errors occuring.
When I ran my first test-program:
(The <> brackets in line 1 seem so delete it but they are there in the code)

```
#include mgl2/mgl.h   
    int main(){
    mglGraph gr;
    gr.FPlot("sin(pi*x)");
    gr.WriteFrame("test.png");
}
```

the compilation with g++ -lmgl went fine.
When trying to run the programm i get:
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libmgl.so.7.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I triple checked to be sure and libmgl.so.7.2.0 is definetely in /usr/local/lib/.
I tried telling g++ this via the -L option but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -lmgl -lpng /shitfile.cpp -o /shitfile
```

care friend